# How do I post an answer on this site?

Tags: discussion

I see how to comment on questions, but not how to actually ANSWER the question. Can someone point me to what the procedure is to accomplish that?

Comment: Hi DeWitt, welcome to the site.  I've moved this to [meta.parenting.se], which is our area for asking questions *about* the site.

Answer (score 4):

To answer a question, there will be a box on the bottom of the page that allows you to type in it, under "Your Answer".  You can post an answer there!

One limitation: if you are trying to answer a protected question, you will require at least 10 reputation on this site (meaning, you have to have earned at least one up-vote on a question or an answer elsewhere on the site first); that applies only to controversial questions or to limit spam on certain questions that seem to attract it.  Those questions will be denoted by a banner near the top of the question.

For more information, you can also go to the [help center](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/help) or take our [tour](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/tour).  Please feel free to ask anything else you're curious about!

Answer (score -1):

Yeah Joes summed it up pretty well. Just click on the question, scroll down, type your answer in the box, then click "post your answer". There are "protected questions" which as said previously require a higher reputation.